# How to populate combo box using VBA code in Access 2010

Tags: vba

I am trying to populate the combo box using vba code in access but unfortunately the combo box is not getting populated neither am I getting any error message. Following Is the VBA code I am using

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.cmbox_cmp_search.Value = ""
    Me.cmbox_date_search.Value = ""

    Dim mycomp_search As String
    cmbox_cmp_search.RowSourceType = Query

    mycomp = "select distinct nre_purchase.scrip_pur from nre_purchase"  

    Me.cmbox_cmp_search.RowSource = mycomp
    Me.cmbox_cmp_search.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Try setting the `RowSourceType` to `"Table/Query"` (including quotes). `cmbox_cmp_search.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"`. And you also never use your `mycomp_search` string variable, and did not declare your `mycomp` string variable. Try to always declare all the variables you will be using.